# How to skip an item in an array in a copy macro from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm new here with something that has had me stumped for weeks.

I have a macro that copies excel ranges from a sheet to a pre-prepared PowerPoint slide, and this is done using an array like below:

```
SlideArr = Array(1, 2, 3)

RangeArr = Array(Output.Range("A1:B1"), Output.Range("A2:B2"), _
  Output.Range("A3:B3"))

For x = LBound(SlideArr) To UBound(SlideArr)
    RangeArr(x).Copy
    Set shp = MyPresentation.Slides(SlideArr(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)
```

Now what this does is copy paste 3 sets of ranges to 3 different slides. My question is if it is possible to code a macro that skips the 2nd slide (array 2), so it will only paste onto slides 1 and 3.

Comment: Yes. Either conditionally check that you're on slide two and run `Continue for` or check that you're on slide one or three and execute your logic. To make a conditional check use `If`.

Comment: How would I use an `if` in this case? Can I just do something like:

`If Array(2)
    Continue for Array(3)
 End If`

Not very familiar with working with arrays as it's my first time. It was a godsent compared to my previous method of havnig a copy-pasting code for each range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 3 items, you have a few options

Like mentioned in the comment (not the most efficient option):

---

```
SlideArr = Array(1, 2, 3)

RangeArr = Array(Output.Range("A1:B1"), Output.Range("A2:B2"), Output.Range("A3:B3"))

For x = LBound(SlideArr) To UBound(SlideArr)
    If x = 1 Or x = 3 Then    'If x is 1 or 3 execute the statements
        RangeArr(x).Copy
        Set shp = MyPresentation.Slides(SlideArr(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)
    End If
Next
```

---

The next one is more useful for more items, but it can work here too

---

```
SlideArr = Array(1, 2, 3)

RangeArr = Array(Output.Range("A1:B1"), Output.Range("A2:B2"), Output.Range("A3:B3"))

'On a 5 itm array, x will become: 1, 3, 5 (yours will iterate with x = 1 and x = 3)

For x = LBound(SlideArr) To UBound(SlideArr) Step 2
    RangeArr(x).Copy
    Set shp = MyPresentation.Slides(SlideArr(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)
Next
```

---

Or, simply don't use a loop:

---

```
RangeArr(1).Copy
Set shp = MyPresentation.Slides(SlideArr(1)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)

RangeArr(3).Copy
Set shp = MyPresentation.Slides(SlideArr(3)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)
```

---

Hope this helps